# Image upload works on desktop but not from mobile camera

Tags: php, android, mobile, camera

Just as the title says, my file uploads properly when on desktop.

I have a Galaxy 6 and I go to the same page and take a picture from my camera and upload it, and it fails.

Here's outputs:
ON DESKTOP:

```
array(5) { ["name"]=> string(17) "1836x3264test.jpg" ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpFRgSWW" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(856934) }
```

ON MOBILE FROM CAMERA:

```
array(5) { ["name"]=> string(14) "12412674172461randomnumbers.jpg" ["type"]=> string(0) "" ["tmp_name"]=> string(0) "" ["error"]=> int(1) ["size"]=> int(0) }
```

Here is my script to replicate this:

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); //attempt to enable CORS
    if(isset($_POST['submit_image'])) {
        var_dump($_FILES['new_image']);
    }
?>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="new_image">Image: </label>
    <input type="file" name="new_image">
    <input type="submit" name="submit_image" value="Submit">
</form>
```

--

I've tried enabling CORS with apache2.conf and php headers, no luck.

The weird thing is I can upload saved Snapchat pictures from Documents, but if I take a picture with camera and try to upload the file in the PHP script from Documents, it doesn't seem to upload. Same output as shown above.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `my file uploads properly when on desktop` ?? From where to where? Dont understand a word.

Answer (score 0):

Your code work as expected on my laptop & my phone (android 5, zenfone 4s), but try this syntax:

```
<input type="file" name="new_image" accept="image/*">
```

For more information see [HTML Media Capture](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-media-capture/)

Comment: Added that attribute and no difference. I'm assuming it's server related as you said it's working as expected for you.
Are you using WAMP or something?
I'm using Ubuntu 14 as the web server with apache and php.